# How to import GHC.Event?

Tags: sockets, haskell

I'm playing around with most recent Haskell platform (2013.2.0.0) on Windows trying to create a simple but fast concurrent socket server. I'm trying to base my work on examples here: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Simple_Servers

That sample, however, doesn't not compile complaining that it

```
 Could not find module `System.Event'
```

After some googling I've found out that all declarations from that module were moved to GHC.Event, which has a remark in its documentation about being 'GHC internal'. Indeed, when i try to `import GHC.Event` I get the same error

```
 Could not find module `GHC.Event'
```

How should I be supposed to import useful functions such as `registerFd` and friends? Is there anything I'm missing in my cabal file? I've got the following:

```
 build-depends:       base ==4.6.*, hslogger == 1.2.3, time == 1.4.0.*, old-locale, network == 2.4.1.2
```

Comment: GHC.Event is in base, so I don't know why you wouldn't be able to import it. Unless perhaps it's not available on Windows. If you start GHCi and type `import GHC.Event`, do you get an error?

Comment: Yes, I have the same error `Could not find module 'GHC.Event'`. That would be a pity if it isn't supported on Windows.

Comment: I don't know much about Haskell on Windows, but maybe we can at least check that you have a sane installation. What happens if you type `ghc-pkg check` at a command prompt?

Comment: I've got MANY warnings from haddock-html and haddock-interaces about missing `html` directory and missing `.haddock` files, but nothing suspicious except these warnings.

Comment: Yeah, I get those warnings also. But it seems your installation is OK. We've reached the limit of my Windows knowledge, so I probably won't be much help. Hopefully someone with more Windows experience will see this and respond.

Comment: In searching for info, I stumbled upon some info that deepens my suspicion that GHC.Event is not available on Windows, at least not on the 32-bit OS: In the source code for [GHC.Conc.IO](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Conc-IO.html#ensureIOManagerIsRunning), all of the imports of GHC.Event are surrounded by `#ifdef mingw32_HOST_OS ... else .. endif` blocks.

Comment: Oh, I see. Probably I really should just stick with forkIO solution for now.